# Why would advance civilization type 2 or 3 still use manpower?

Tags: science-based

Why would an advance type II or III civilization would still use manpower? Why wouldn't they just use android and a.i as soldiers or workers in manual labors?

Comment: Are you specifically asking about manual labour and/or soldiering or do you mean in any work context generally (e.g. like management) ?

Comment: Because any society that reached type 2 or 3 is populated by people who want to do stuff, otherwise it would of died off/plateaued long before.

Comment: Of course, having said that there's a kind of reverse, which is that whilst programming resilient AI might be easier than programming humans, humans are far less capable of doing damage if they malfunction.

Comment: I suggest you look at the answers to the possible duplicate, hand crafted, custom, or home designed  merchandise is more common now than any time since industrialization began, mechanization just makes it easier.

Comment: This question(even if probably may benefit by improvements) is not a duplicate of the question mentioned, because it is more specific than abstract some variety of creatures may or may not do some job in undefined context/circumstances. Here context is more defined, it a more narrow question. As an example there only 2 distinct situations to consider based on the proportion of the number of people / energy available - when it is high and when it is low. Generally, they rather do not do it in an usual sense in any of those case, but for different reasons.

Comment: @MolbOrg, a narrow version of a general question is, from SE's perspective, still the same question because any answer you provide for it can (and should) be applied to the earlier question.  To express that another way: if the union of this question and its predecessor completely overlap, they're the same question.  If the union of the two overlap some, they may not be the same question.  If the union of the two has no overlap at all, they're different questions.

Comment: @JBH long time disappointed how you guys consistently fail to see differences in technological questions, mention that just as feedback to think about. Not so important in the case, probably OP does not need that kind of answer. But here the example of a question, F and f are some functions, f is polynomial, F defined on x. Where F has equal values in those 2 cases: F(f(x)), F(x^2) - not the best question, just an example. Second is a subset of the first, but it can have some meaningful answer, where the first we can't tell because not knowing the f(x).

Comment: K2,3 do provide enough specifics(and is extension of K1, which is near future, which is more definitive) to context to be able to provide more meaningful answers, and which does not boil to 0 - humans stay humans/boredom/curiosity/necessity to learn/pride/fun/any other human invariant. I may agree on similarity, and probably those human-related answers are what OP is looking for and it will suffice for him. I bet the question will never see a proper edit, and descision is rather correct, just reason is wrong.

Comment: @MolbOrg, we are as bound by SE's general policies as we are our own.  If you want to debate SE policy, please do so on [meta.se].  We do not have the authority to change it here.